# Windows Server 2003 increase service limit from 25

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

I am trying to run one applications in multiple times, however, when the instances reaches to 25 it stops. I can't launch it anymore nor start any other applications, how can increase this limit or make it unlimited?

P.S. I also, heard that Windows can host unlimited number of services running under LocalSystem, is that true?

Thank you,
Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your application is probably running into a resource limit, like PagedPool, NonPagedPool, or Desktop Heap, or something else like that. You'll need to run some tools to figure out what. ProcessExplorer is a very good place to start. There's also a Desktop Heap Monitoring tool.

I don't know if Windows will host an unlimited number of services under LocalSystem (or any other account), I'm sure you'll run into a resource limit or max at at 32,000 or so. But I don't think there's an arbitrary lower limit. If you have lots of questions like this, you should start reading books and blogs by Mark Russinovich.

Comment: Agreed. This is a problem with whatever the OP is trying to run, not with Windows.